# Java GUI does not fully load after addMouseListener event is triggered

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, mouse-listeners

I have the following code to track what a user selects in a table, after a user selects a chat conversation i want to hide the `JPanel` that contains the table and display the `JPanel` that instead contains the chat conversation. See my current code for doing this:

```
       table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
               if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                   JTable target = (JTable) e.getSource();
                   int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                   int column = target.getSelectedColumn();


                   // loop through all elements in the table
                   for (int i = 0; i < listmodel.size(); i++) {

                       // get the table item associated with the current element
                       final Object object = listmodel.get(i);
                       if (object instanceof ListItem) {
                           ListItem listitem = (ListItem) object;

                           if (table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString() == listitem.getText()) {

                               // Show the chat conversation (this is where the GUI for some reason does not fully load)
                               SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                   public void run() {
                                       pnlMainTableWrapper.setVisible(false); // Contains the table
                                       pnlChatMsgs.setVisible(true);
                                       pnlSendMsg.setVisible(true);
                                       pnlRight.setVisible(true);

                                       pnlChatMsgs.validate();
                                       pnlChatMsgs.repaint();
                                   }
                               });
                           }
                       }
                   }                    
               }
           }
       });
```

For some strange reason not all GUI components in the `JPanel` `pnlChatMsgs`are being loaded, these components are just white.

Any ideas whats causing this behavior?

Comment: Should you handle this in `done` method?

Comment: @Pranalee what do you mean with `done` method?

Comment: isn't easier to use JPopupMenu

Comment: I think you are using Swing, Swing is not thread safe, try to look at java api doc where they have addressed this threading issue.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see code trying to use two components in the same place it is better to use the [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and let it manager which component is visible at any time.

If you try to manage it on your own then the code should be something like this at design time:

```
JPanel parent = new JPanel();
JPanel child1 = new JPanel();
JPanel child2 = new JPanel();
child2.setVisible(false);
parent.add( child1 );
parent.add( child2 );
```

Then at run time when you swap panels you would do:

```
child1.setVisible(false);
child2.setVisible(true);
parent.revalidate();
parent.repaint();
```

I still recommend the CardLayout so you don't reinvent the wheel.

Also, the invokeLater() is probably not necessary since all Swing event code already executes on the EDT.